# Reverse a list of HTML paragraph via Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, reverse

I'm using Javascript (no jQuery) to create a list of paragraphs to get the best time to go to sleep (based on the REM sleep cycle) and show it on a page, [here's the code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wbhGl).

```
function sleepnow() {
    var result = '';
    var a = new Date();
    var hour = a.getHours();

    var minutes = a.getMinutes() + 14;
    if (minutes > 60) {
        minutes = minutes - 60;
        hour = hour + 1;
    }

    for (var counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++) {
        if (minutes < 30) {
            minutes = minutes + 30;
        } else {
            minutes = minutes - 30;
            hour = hour + 1;
        }
        hour = hour + 1;

        if (hour >= 24) {
            if (hour === 24) {
                hour = 0;
            } else if (hour === 25) {
                hour = 1;
            }
        }

        if (hour > 9) {
            result = result + '<p>' + hour;
        } else {
            result = result + '<p>0' + hour;
        }

        if (minutes > 9) {
            result = result + ':' + minutes + '</p>';
        } else {
            result = result + ':0' + minutes + '</p>';
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('sleepnow').innerHTML = result;
}
```

How can I reverse that list to show the farther one first and so on? I tried for an hour with .reverse() but I can't get it to work, it just flips everything, < p > tags included, breaking everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd separate the data from the html a little more.  Instead of building a string, build an array of times.  Then you can loop through it in reverse order when you build the html string.

```
1. create data structure, contains only numbers, no html (model)
2. convert data to html (view)

var html = '';
for (var counter = YOURDATA.length-1; counter >= 0; counter--) {
    var t = YOURDATA[counter];
    html += ' build your string ' + t + '...';
}
```

Also this case should be fine, but be careful with special characters in the raw data (&<>\"").  Generally you should escape all the data, for an html context.

Comment: I agree with @user1389596 100%. My answer was somewhat **without changing anything else**. What I'm trying to say drbernardi by this is that you're bound to get in trouble again soon if you don't follow user1389596's advice

Answer (score 0):

First of all: The answer is: By using an intermediate accumulator string variable **currentOne** which accumulates normally and by accumulating in the other order in the result: **result = currentOne + result** instead of **result = result + currentOne**. Enjoy:

```
function sleepnow() {
var result = '';
var a = new Date();
var hour = a.getHours();

var minutes = a.getMinutes() + 14;
if (minutes > 60) {
    minutes = minutes - 60;
    hour = hour + 1;
}

for (var counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++) {
var currentOne = "";

    if (minutes < 30) {
        minutes = minutes + 30;
    } else {
        minutes = minutes - 30;
        hour = hour + 1;
    }
    hour = hour + 1;

    if (hour >= 24) {
        if (hour === 24) {
            hour = 0;
        } else if (hour === 25) {
            hour = 1;
        }
    }

    if (hour > 9) {
        currentOne = currentOne + '<p>' + hour;
    } else {
        currentOne = currentOne + '<p>0' + hour;
    }

    if (minutes > 9) {
        currentOne = currentOne + ':' + minutes + '</p>';
    } else {
        currentOne = currentOne + ':0' + minutes + '</p>';
    }

result = currentOne + result;
}
document.getElementById('sleepnow').innerHTML = result;
}
```

Secondly: Please don't make external links without describing what's on the other side thoroughly. External links can expire, become irrelevant, etc.

Third: You made quite a mess in that code right there :)

Comment: Thanks, to be fair the code is not 100% mine, it's just adapted to make it suits my needs, maybe I should try making it on my own, I can see its flaws and I'm less than a beginner :)

Comment: It's good to keep your enthusiasm. Welcome aboard ! and keep up the good work :)